# Prove the formula of directional derivatives in cylindrical coordinate system??

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, cylindrical-coordinates

The problem is:

In cylindrical coordinate system, we have a scalar field: p = (r, $\theta$, z)
Prove:
$$\nabla p = \frac{\partial p}{\partial r}e_r + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta}e_\theta + \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}e_z$$

Here is my work:

r = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ; $\theta = arctan\frac{y}{x}$ ; z = z

Then:

p = (r, $\theta$, z) = p ($\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, acrtan\frac{y}{x},z)= f (x,y,z)$ (convert to cartesian coordinate system)

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} \frac{x}{r}-\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta} \frac{y}{r^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} \frac{y}{r}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta} \frac{x}{r^2}$$
$$......$$

We must show:$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial r} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2}$$ (I convert again to cylindrical coordinate system)

but I got:
$$ \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\frac{1}{r^2}} 
 \neq \frac{\partial p}{\partial r}$$

Where was I wrong?? Are there any other shorter way to prove this ?

Comment: No, you don't want to show equality of the norms, you need to show that the *vectors* are equal. Further, since the $z$ coordinate is untransformed, the final equation you have is the correct one (assuming $f = p$), and the one you set out to prove is incorrect.

Comment: For a quick solution - firstly, the $z$ coordinate is untransformed, so you don't need to worry about the $z$ terms. Now note that $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$, and that $\hat{r} = \cos \theta \hat{x} + \sin \theta \hat{y},$ and $\hat{\theta} = -\sin \theta \hat{x} + \cos \theta \hat{y}$. Now, by the total derivative rule, $\partial_r p = \partial_x p \, \partial_r x + \partial_y p \, \partial_r y = \partial_x p \cos \theta + \partial_y p \sin \theta. $ Thus,...

Comment: ... $\partial_r p \,\hat{r} = \partial_xp \cos^2 \theta \,\hat{x} + \partial_yp \sin^2 \theta \,\hat{y}$. Now do the same for $\partial_\theta p \,\hat{\theta}$.

Comment: why is the one I set out to prove incorrect ?

Comment: Well, suppose you have a vector in (2D) polar coordinates $u = u_r \,\hat{r} + u_\theta \,\hat{\theta},$ and a vector in (2D) cartesian coordinates $v = v_x \,\hat{x} + v_y \,\hat{y}$. Then (in general), $u = v \implies u_r^2 + u_\theta^2= v_x^2 + v_y^2, $ not $u_r^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2$ - the whole lengths of the vectors have to be the same, and the $\theta$ component has a magnitude. It might help to draw a diagram. Also note that this is a one way implication. To show two vectors are equal, it does not suffice to show that they have the same length.